# How to sort data by _version in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

As I am able to sort data using score like

```
    {
  "version":true,
  "_source":false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}

  }
}
```

Please let me know How can I do the same with _version. By default Fielddata is not supported on field _version. So may be I am missing some thing. 
Is there any specific setting to query with version? 
Please help!

Comment: Basically you can't do this. What is the use case?

Comment: I have some document which have version more than 1. 
I just want to know how many document has version more than 1, may be in a sorted list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, and usually you don't have to.
See this thread:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-by--version-and-show--version-in-elasticsearch-query/22024/2

> While using the _version might seem to work in certain cases, I would 
>   recommend to never use it for anything else than optimistic locking of 
>   updates. In particular, versions do not carry any meaning: they might look 
>   like the number of times a document has been modified but it is not always 
>   the case (for instance if you create a new document which has the same ID 
>   as a document that you just deleted, the version number of the new document 
>   will not be 1), and more importantly it is an implementation detail, this 
>   behaviour might change in the future.

`_version` field is not indexed so you can't use it in queries.
You can create you custom version field and handle it manually.