# elastic search aggregation sum of document version

Tags: elasticsearch

My problem statement is as follows
Every time a transaction  happens I will go and create/update a transaction entry. 
Transaction object looks something as below

```
_id: <tenantId>_<productId>_<trasction_month>
{
   "tenant" : "tenantId",
   "product" : "productId",
   "timestamp" : <epoch timestamp utc>
   "month" : "transaction month"
}
```

Note, we can have thousands of transactions in a given month.
For a given tenant, I want to  find out the total transactions per month.

I was hoping something as below

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "transactions": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "_version"
          }
       }
    }
}
```

But the above does'nt works. It gives the below error

```
{
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [_version] of type [_version]"
}
```

What's the best we can do here ? I don't want to maintain my own versions within the document as each update will require search / followed by update. This will put a lot of strain on the es cluster as our transactions can be very frequent in a multi tenant environment.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to play with the `_version` field. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789869/how-to-sort-data-by-version-in-elasticsearch So your best bet is to add a custom `version` field that you increment on each update. Using a partial update script, you don't need to search for the document when updating it, you simply have a little script that does it for you, e.g. `ctx._source.version++`

Comment: @Val is right. You can't do it other way around. And the script he suggests should be easy to implement and not actually needing a search and then update as you said. The script will be included in your regular update that you are already doing.